# How to obtain the content-length field from all http response headers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am trying to create a simple extension for google chrome which can measure data usage. For this i need to view the content-length field of every incoming http/https response header. I tried the documentation on google and all i was able to come up was the following. First one is the **background.js** javascript file:-

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){
  console.log(details.responseHeaders);
},
{urls: ["http://*/*"]},["responseHeaders"]);
```

Following is my manifest.json code :-

```
    {
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "Getting started example",
      "description": "Toggle Data Usage monitor",
      "version": "1.0",

      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
      "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "DataUsageMonitor.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
   } ],
      "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
       },
      "permissions": [
    "http://*/*", "activeTab", "tabs", "webRequest"]}
```

All this code is supposed to do is print the response headers of all responses to the chrome console. But i get nothing in the chrome console when i run it.
I am fairly new to javascript and very new to chrome extension development so please go easy on me.

Edit 1: Added the content script section in manifest.json and now the console says 'Cannot read property 'onHeadersReceived'

Edit 2: Added the **webReqest** part into a different javascript file called **background.js** and registered it as a background page in **manifest.json** I don't get the "can't read webRequest.OnheadersReceived" error anymore but the console is still empty

Comment: Have you included your JS file in your `manifest.json`?

Comment: Thank you so much. I have added it as a content script. But now the console gives the error "cannot read property 'onHeadersReceived' " But i don't understand. onHeadersReceived is a member of webRequest right?

Comment: Actually in order to add the listener, i need 'webRequest.onHeadersREceived.addEventListener' part. So i can't use the console.log(details) idea without adding a listener for responses